# Target Top not working in Chrome

Tags: html

Target top not working in chrome is there any replacement for it  ? But it works correctly in firefox
I am using frames.

```
 target = "_top"
```

Comment: Your question is far too vague. Please elaborate and create an example that reproduces the issue.